# Problem in ant when using a directory with whitespaces

Tags: android, ant, whitespace

i want to build an Android project using ant. i used `ant install` but gives me an error becuase i am working in `C:\Documents and Settings` so the spaces are a problem it worked well if i created the project in a directory with no spaces like `C:\Test` any body know how to overcome that space problem in ant

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Or use '/' instead of '\'. It works the same in Ant on Windows and is a little easier to read.

appserver.home="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0"